# How do I change checkbox input style so it appears a user is tapping on label rather than actual box?

Tags: html, css, checkbox, input

I'm creating a project with HTML and CSS and I want to have options that can be chosen using the checkbox input. However, I want to alter the styling so that the actual box is hidden and the label text can be tapped to indicate a choice instead. I am able to hide the box by lowering its opacity to zero, but I'm struggling to move the invisible box on top of the text so that it appears the text is being tapped rather than the box. This will ultimately be a part of an iOS app.

Here is what I have: [Current view with visible boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G9gEj.png) and [Current view with hidden boxes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXUPs.png)

The look of the hidden boxes is what I want, but for the background color to change the user has to tap to the left of the text (where the invisible box is).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="full-input preferences">
  <input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Sports" class="preference"><label for="sports">Sports</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="pets" value="Pets" class="preference"><label for="pets">Pets</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="movies" value="Movies" class="preference"><label for="movies">Movies</label>
  <input type="checkbox" name="food" value="Food" class="preference"><label for="food">Food</label>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.preferences {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 2;
}

.preference {
  margin: 0 .5em;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
}

input[type=checkbox] + label {
  border: 1px solid #38A3B8;
  padding: .3em;
  border-radius: 5px;
  min-width: 3em;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {
    background: #38A3B8;
    color: white;
}
```

I've tried using absolute positioning, but it causes there to be only one box for all of the inputs rather than one box per input for some reason. I've also tried putting the input tag inside the label tag, but from there I can't change the background color when the box is checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but for the background color to change the user has to tap to the left of the text (where the invisible box is)

Well that’s because you did not *correctly* associate the labels with the input fields …

```
<input type="checkbox" name="sports" value="Sports" class="preference">
<label for="sports">Sports</label>
```

The `for` attribute has to refer to the *ID* of an input field, putting only the *name* in there is not enough.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="sports" name="sports" value="Sports" class="preference">
<label for="sports">Sports</label>
```

This way, the label is correctly associated with the input field, so that clicking the label text will now toggle the checkbox status.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I'm new to vanilla HTML/CSS development and have yet to learn all the nuances. This was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a padding to the Checkboxes that they don't look weird. (The actual size that the Checkbox would occupy)

```
input[type=checkbox] {
  opacity: 0;
  padding-right: 10px (or whichever size that fits);
}
```

Hopefully, this answer helped you resolve the problem (in any way). 
Thank you very much.

Comment: That's a good suggestion, but it doesn't work. I don't think you can style the box itself like that.

Comment: @SpencerAttick That's Disappointing. Good luck with an answer.